# POCO::PostgreSQL Cache

Tags: c++, postgresql, caching, poco-libraries

I want to completely load a database into RAM and update this cache once an hour. I use the framework POCO C++, PostgreSQL 12.3 Ubuntu.
And in general, I would like to configure the database and monitor the cache (get the data that is there and monitor the success of loading them into the cache)

The question is how to configure the cache in Poco:PostgreSQL?

Comment: And what is your question? Are you asking for approval? Opinions? What library to use?

Comment: @Botje The question is how to configure the cache in Poco:PostgreSQL?

Comment: That's not how you typically use a database, so I do not think Poco natively supports your use case. You will have to write code to load the contents into your own data structures yourself.

Comment: @Botje Thanks for the answer! So I myself need to create a cache from the models, where some identifier of the model will be the key, when I query the database, I first go to the cache and see if there is an object with such an ID? There will be a small question, of course, where to embed this search in the Poco library)

Comment: Again, this is not a usual workflow, so I doubt Poco supports it. In your own `find_object` function you would first search the cache and only then consult Postgres.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you need to do this caching? Have you tried writing it as a regular "online" database application first? That is a lot simpler and faster to get off the ground.

Comment: Some databases will weigh quite a lot in our application, so I guess if we do not load the models into RAM, the service will slow down. At the same time, I would like programmers to send regular queries to the database:

 `insert_client << "INSERT INTO persons VALUES ($ 1, $ 2, $ 3, $ 4, $ 5, $ 6, $ 7, $ 8)", keywords :: use (body), keywords :: now;`

and did not suspect about a cache.

Comment: Since you qualified your answer with "I guess", you do not have hard numbers yet? I implore you to try the simplest approach first. Facebook and YouTube got to a very respectable scale on MySQL alone before they had to resort to different storage/caching models. I would not worry about "slowing down" with PostgreSQL before you hit millions of users. Get it working first, _then_ scale it up.

Comment: @Botje Understood thanks!